# How can I make a Roth IRA contribution AFTER filing taxes for 2010?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, income-tax

I just e-filed my 2010 taxes and have received a direct deposit of my refund already.  I just realized I'd like to make a contribution to my Roth IRA (and my wife's) for 2010.  How can I do this?  Do I need to file an amended return?

Answer (score 11):

No, you do not need to file an amended return, because Roth contributions are after tax contributions and are not reported on your return (UNLESS you over-contribute in which case you may have to pay a penalty on your return).

Make the contribution now before April 15 and you don't need to worry about it.  Just make sure you are within the required contribution limits.

Comment: By "now," specifically before the regular filing deadline (April 18th 2011).

Comment: Doesn't the original question and this answer only apply to Traditional IRAs? Roth's are post-tax and have no difference in your filed taxes, correct?

Comment: @DuckMaestro Duh, you are correct. There is no change in the taxes because Roth contributions don't get reported.  Changed answer.